# Pop Up using LeftletdirectiveMarker.map.click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am relative new to Angularjs and i am currently working on a project but I hit an obstacle. I've been trying multiple ways to do this but Im all out of idea. Here is a picture of what I want to do:

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw3Ps.png)

So on this picture, there are icons and what I want to do is upon clicking an icon, a pop-up window will appear. If you look at the shaded area on top right, that is how I want my the window to be and look like as I already built a template for it and right now the template is static div being displayed.

Here is my code so far:

```
$scope.cameraData = [];
$scope.markers = [];
$http.get($scope.docRoot + 'public/data/streetcams.json')
    .success(function(data) {

        $scope.cameraData = data;
        for(var marker in $scope.cameraData) {
            if($scope.cameraData.hasOwnProperty(marker)) {
                $scope.cameraData[marker].icon = cameraIcon;
                $scope.cameraData[marker].layer = 'video';
            }
        }
        $scope.markers = $scope.cameraData;


    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log("Unable to load streecam data file");
    });



$scope.windowOption = {
    show:false
};
var x, y;
$scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMarker.map.click", function(event, args) {
    console.log("this is where the marker is");
    console.log (args.latlng.lat, args.latlng.lng);
    for ( var marker in $scope.markers) {
       x = args.latlng.lat;
       y = args.latlng.lng;
        if (marker.lat === x && marker.lng === y ) {
            $scope.windowOption.show = !$scope.windowOption.show;
        }
    }*/
});

$scope.closePopupOnClick = function () {
    $scope.windowOption.show = false;

};
```

So $scope.markers contains the information of all icons (title, lat and longitude) and my idea is to retrieve the latitude and longitude of each click event and compare that with latitude and longitude of each marker in the markers array, if they are equal then show to popup window. But it's not working and Im not sure what else to do. Any tips will help!

Thanks!

Comment: I know that "args" from leafletdirective.marker.clikc is an object after a marker on the map is clicked; however, im not sure how to access the information of that object. Im getting errors of "lat" and "lng" are undefined.